# Linux missing tty groups

Tags: linux, tty, serial-port

I am currently working on Linux 32 bit 18.04 Version.I have a product which it is an all in one PC that used for can-bus message read write and other functions.I am trying to develop Qt5 Application that read can messages due to its documentation.

While I am trying to use the PC Can-bus SDK it shows me to use communication /dev/ttyA0 path which I don't have it in the directory.I wont even be able to execute sample code without determining the /dev/path correctly.

My question is how tty groups appears.Is it coming with OS system or is it appearing when cable is connected to the device.

I had changed the OS system from Windows Embedded 8 to Ubuntu 32 bit myself(Product data sheet; supports Ubuntu OS).I might be lack of some driver updates that firm provides,but I am not sure.

An extra information that I have tried all the /dev/paths to execute sample code and between 30-40 tty and ttyS groups,One tty group executed the sample;which it is /dev/ttyUSB2.

But unfortunately when I tried to can read operation;it gives error that buffer is empty;nothing to read.

It would be very helpful to get any information about this situation.I am very new to Linux environment and can-bus protocols,so any help appreciated.